# What is the right pattern (EIP) to query two different backend rest endpoint and the then get the first response using Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm exposing a rest endpoint (eg: `/catalogue/{id}`) and I have to send this request to two different backend services (`backend1` and `backend2`) to query them in parallel. But just one should reply with a query result...
I think the Aggregator Strategy does not make sense in this case...
I've seen some examples using enrich, but also does not make sense to me...

I want get the response from the first backend service that return an HTTP 200 with my query result.
I would appreciate any advice on how to implement this using the right pattern (EIP)

Comment: You could use the Camel multicast component with parallelProcessing enabled to call both backends in parallel. You'd still need a simple aggregation strategy to produce the result of the multicast. Multicast waits until both calls complete though, so with parallelProcessing enabled the backend taking the longest time to complete would determine the multicast execution time, which might not be what you want...

Comment: The essential issue seems to be: how to make the parallel processing within a multicast end whenever the first thread of work is complete.

Comment: @SebastianBrandt that is right. I managed to implement this scenario using this approach: multicast (parallel) with a simple aggregator that check the HTTP response from both calls and generating a common result. I'll try to post the code snippet here soon. 

Thanks.

Comment: @Darius X. I think that is not possible using multicast. To achive the behaviour that calls are made concurrently and the fastest response only is processed, a combination of Camel components could be used: a seda producer with multipleConsumers enabled to publish the request. Each backend call would be initiated from its own seda consumer route. The results would then need to run through an idempotent consumer that filters out the seconds result. You'd define some unique header before the seda producer is invoked to be able to filter correctly in the idempotent consumer later.

Comment: @Sebastian, Yeah. But, the one problem I see is that he is exposing a REST endpoint. So, I think your solution would also have to be combined with something that took the first response (or waited for the first response) and returned that to the caller.

Comment: Guys, see my current approach impl to achieve this: https://github.com/rafaeltuelho/shop-catalogue-aggregator

Rest endpoint that dispatches the multicast calls to the backends: `/src/main/java/io/github/microservices/demo/service/CamelRouter.java#L64-L72`

Direct routes to handle backends' responses: 
`/src/main/java/io/github/microservices/demo/service/CamelRouter.java#L99-L137` 

The Aggregator impl.: `src/main/java/io/github/microservices/demo/service/CatalogueQueryAggregationStrategy.java`

Comment: According to your code, both back-end services will reply, and you want to wait for both. So, I guess I misunderstood the original question. But, if you are going to do both in parallel, and aggregate the results of both then it looks fine.